# Align a string with dashes in std::stringstream

Tags: c++, std, stringstream

I am trying to write a set of number into a stringstream looking like this:

```
SOME_TEXT    12-23-43    SOME_OTHER_TEXT
```

12-23-43 are three numbers divided by dash ('-'), numbers can be 1 or 2-digits (like 1-2-3 or 12-1-47 so the length of the whole set differs). The whole set should be aligned to the left and take exactly 12 characters including spaces. When I try to apply std::left manipulator it works only for the first number. How can I do it?

Comment: apply `std::left` before each term?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using another `ostringstream` :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
  std::ostringstream oss1;
  oss1 << 5 << "-" << 31 << "-" << 6;
  std::ostringstream oss;
  oss << "SOME_TEXT    " << std::setw(12) << std::left << oss1.str() << "SOME_OTHER_TEXT";
  std::cout << oss.str() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Got this 0xfffffd7ffc8029e8 instead of 1-96-4. sprintf worked though but it's kinda uncool, I guess.

Comment: What is your code ? It's working for me. I edited to show a complete example.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with sprintf, I'm surprised though it can't be done with stringstream:

```
char buffer[12];
sprintf(buffer, "%d-%d-%d", n1, n2, n3);            
output << std::setw(12) << std::left << buffer;
```

Comment: You mix C and C++ styles. You can't do it if you want to print objects instead of numbers.

Comment: Well, I can do whatever I want, last time I checked. Seriously, suggest something better, true C++ style, I beg you. Nothing worked so far.

Comment: My answer with another ostringstream is working well. Not for you ?

Comment: Then, what happens ? Compilation error ? Execution error ? What is your code ? I cant help you without knowing what you do.